# Check for Point Collinearity and rearrange line

Tags: geometry

imagine you are having a 2D object, which looks like this:
$$
l = (p_1,p_2,...,p_n)
$$
with $p_i = (x_i, y_i)$.
It may be possible that $p_1 = p_n$, or that $l$ only contains two points, which are not the same. (Am i correct that even if $p_1 = p_n$ the object is still considered a line-like object ? Since in this case it would basically represent the shell of a polygon without a surface.)

My Question is:
In $l$ there are points which are *not collinear*, meaning that $l$ is not just a straight line. Now my goal is to extract all straight lines from $l$, such that $l$ is seperated into a set of new lines. If you would plot the new lines all together, it would be equivalent to plotting $l$.

Does someone has an idea how to do that correctly, and how this process is adequately notated?

Greetings !

Comment: If your set $l$ is ordered, and you're trying to draw the line segments from one point to the next, you could do each line segment like this: $(1-t)p_i+t p_{i+1},$ as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: How exactly do you want to seperate $l$ into new lines? Do you want to seperate the polygon in a minimal partition or do you want to draw only new segments of each line $[p_i,p_{i+1}]$?

Comment: If i use $(p_{i}, p_{i+1})$ to create new lines this would result in a giant set of lines. As an example, imagine $l = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,4), (1,5) \}$, in this case i want the result to be a set of two lines : {(1,1), (3,3)} and {(3,3),(1,5)} instead of 4 lines like in the approach of using $(p_i, p_{i+1})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $V:= \emptyset$.

Now, for $i = 1,\dots, n-1$, do the following:

- If $p_i = p_{i+1}$, continue.
- Check, whether there is a tupel $(a,b,X)\in V$ s.t.
  $\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span} p_i,p_{i+1} \in a +
     \span{\{b-a\}}$.

  - If that is the case, write $p_i = a + \lambda (b-a)$ and $p_{i+1} = a
       + \mu (b-a)$. Without loss we may assume $\lambda > \mu$. Now, replace $(a,b,X)\in V$ by $\DeclareMathOperator{\contract}{contract} 
       (a,b,\contract{(X\cup \{[\mu, \lambda]\})})$, where $\contract(\{Y_1, \dots, Y_k\}):=\begin{cases}\contract(\{Y_1,\dots ,Y_k\}\backslash\{Y_i,Y_j\}\cup\{Y_i \cup Y_j\})& \text{if there are $i\neq j$ s.t. $Y_i \cap Y_j \neq \emptyset$}\\
    \{Y_1, \dots , Y_k\} & \text{else}\end{cases}$
  - Else, add $(p_i,p_{i+1}, \{[0,1]\})$ to $V$.

Now, you can draw all lines you need as follows: For every $(a,b,X) \in V$ and for all $[\mu,\lambda]\in X$, draw $[a+\mu (b-a), a+\lambda (b-a)] := \{a + \xi (b-a) \space | \space \xi \in [\mu, \lambda]\}$.

Comment: Late but very appreciated <3